# How to make a queryset combining multiple ANDs and ORs in django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need to filter something like this:

```
(status = 0 OR status = 4) OR (parameter = NONE AND status = 1)
```

how to I translate this into a django queryset?

**Possible solutions**

Attempt 1:

```
obj.filter(Q(status=0) | Q(status=4) | (Q(par=None) & Q(status = 1)))

Real query:
it = it.filter( (Q(respond_status=0) | Q(respond_status=4)) | (Q(respond_status=1) & Q(plant__isnull=True) ))
                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Attempt 2:

```
obj_total = []
    for obj in objs:
        if (obj.status == 0 or obj.status == 4) or (obj.status == 0 and obj.param == None):
            obj_total.append(obj)

    objs = Obj.objects.filter(id__in=[x.id for x in obj_total])
```

This is realy inefficient

Comment: Your first one looks correct. What is indicated as invalid syntax?

Comment: I've pasted the original query @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 2):

Use the django [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

two constraints linked by AND (&)
and one linked by or (|)

```
from django.db.models import Q

Model.objects.filter( (Q(status=1) | Q(status=4)) | ( Q(para=param) & Q(status=1) )
```

Comment: Sorry, this solution does not represent the required logic statement